# How can I exclude one file to be mounted from an entire disk

Tags: c++, linux, mount

Am trying to perform mounts using c++ but I want to exclude one particular file being mounted as I dont want this file to be touched by any other process.

Following is my source code:

```
#include <sys/mount.h>

#define DROOT "/rd/daemon-root"

if (mkdir(DROOT, 0744) && errno != EEXIST)
    cout<<endl<<"Can't create "<<DROOT <<" (" << strerror(errno) << ")";

int r = mount("/", DROOT, "ext4", MS_BIND, NULL);
  if (r == -1)
    cout<<endl<<"Mounting of " DROOT " failed (" << strerror(errno) << ")";
  else
    cout<<endl<<DROOT<<" mounted successfully";
```

Now my system root contains /etc directory and I dont want it to be mounted as the process using  the mount changes it.

Is  there any way to avoid the mounting of a particular directory or else make it one way change such that changes on the mount dont affect the actual.

PS - Have already tried options listed https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount_002dUnmount_002dRemount.html but nothing helps. Not even MS_ReadOnly

Answer (score 2):

You cannot exclude a single file. To exclude a directory, you can mount something on top of that directory to effectively hide it. However, you have to be careful to ensure you only hide the directory in the bind mount, and not in the original directory as well. You do this by making the first bind mount private. Using shell commands, it would look like this:

```
mkdir $DROOT
mkdir /tmp/empty
mount -o bind --make-private / $DROOT
mount -o bind /tmp/empty $DROOT/tmp/
```

In C (minus error checking):

```
char path_to_hide[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(path_to_hide, sizeof path_to_hide, "%s/%s", DROOT, "etc");

mkdir(DROOT, 0744);
mkdir("/tmp/empty", 0);

mount("/", DROOT, NULL, MS_BIND | MS_PRIVATE, NULL);
mount("/tmp/empty", path_to_hide, NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this out but yet if some random process is working inside the DROOT/etc and changing files there, the original /etc files get changed too.